# EFCore load childs entity without load the parent data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the next issue.

```
public class Segment : EntityWithIntId
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SubCampaignId { get; set; }
    public List<Template> Templates { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubCampaignId")]
    public SubCampaign SubCampaign { get; set; }
}
```

model for templates.

```
public class Template : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int SegmentId { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SegmentId")]
    public Segment Segment { get; set; }
}
```

this is my query.

```
_dbcontext.segments.Include(x => x.templates).ToList();
```

I want to load all templates entities  that have the segment entity.

The problem is that when the templates are loaded, within each template the segment relationship is reloaded and again the segment reloads all the templates that are children and in this way a circular reference is created

sorry, I didn't know how to express myself.

I have the following relationship.

segment has a list of templates

each template has a list of groups
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy9gH.png)
each group has a list of services.

The idea is to consult the segment and that he bring me all the templates and that each template bring the groups and that each group bring the services.

the problem is that as each entity has a relationship with the parent, the system is reloading the parent's data automatically.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNXAx.png)

Comment: I have the following relationship.

segment has a list of templates

each template has a list of groups

each group has a list of services.

The idea is to consult the segment and that he bring me all the templates and that each template bring the groups and that each group bring the services.

the problem is that as each entity has a relationship with the parent, the system is reloading the parent's data automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` for such query:

```cs
var query = 
   from s in _dbcontext.segments
   from t in s.templates
   from g in t.Groups
   from svc in g.Services
   select svc;
```

Comment: That is terribly inefficient since you are doing a vectorial product with your tables. Instead of multiple from statements to include tables, you should be doing joins.

Comment: @PepeAlvarez, I'm pretty sure that this query will be translated to joins automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try to start from Template class then using ThenInclude from Entity Framework Core like this :

```
_dbcontext.templates.Include(x => x.Segment).ThenInclude(x => x.Templates).ToList();
```

I think it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Default, the relationship objects store as `IQueryable` object. They nerver load if you haven't touched on them before or used `Include`.
When you select child nodes from parent node, datas of parent display in childs node because it has loaded before (reference).

Try this to see more:

```
List<Templates> templates;
(using dbcontext = new YourContent())
  templates = dbcontext.segments.SelectMany(x => x.templates).ToList();
```

The parent node `Segment` has no value in `templates`.